# Changing color when double clicked in the getListCellRendererComponent

Tags: java, swing, jlist, double-click, mouselistener

How can I change color when I double click the cell of `JList`?
Is there a way adding a `MouseListener` within `DefaultListCellRenderer`?

```
public class Renderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{

 @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) 
    {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if(isSelected){
            c.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I has a similar situation recently where I wanted to double click table entries and have them added in a list.  The trick was to:

- Add a boolean in the table to denote 'has been added to list'.
- On double click (add the row to list &) set that value to true.
- When rendering, check the boolean and decide how to render it.